# Operations panel greyed out

Tags: modeling

Using Blender 2.8, for a few different operations the panel window with the parameters gets greyed out for some reason, for example Randomize Transform. Everything is selected, in object mode, but none of the transforms are available to change.  Can someone point out what im missing?

[image]

Comment: You don't have an active object selected.